# Is it beneficial to include ORDER BY fields in the list of SELECT fields?

Tags: mysql, performance, order-by, query-performance

I'm just wondering when you do a query and you use `ORDER BY` should the fields you use in the `ORDER BY` clause always be included in the `SELECT` list even if you don't need them? Is this beneficial in some way?

Comment: It's completely down to your individual requirements. Do you need the column? Yes/No.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no benefit to including the ORDER BY columns in the SELECT list. On the contrary, having unrequired columns in the SELECT list incurs a fractional overhead in run time and a larger one in maintenance.

Comment: Ok thanks. I was thinking by including the data in the result set it lessened the work MySQL needed to do to get the data to know how to sort the results.

Comment: @Brett the query *needs to read* all the columns used, no matter the clause. The SELECT clause only specifies which columns will be sent to the client.